# mysql, forcing primary keys to be unique across two tables

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have two mysql tables both with primary keys (the records 'id' field).  The tables are used by a perl application.  I want to build a hash (in perl) that includes records from both tables keyed off of their ids.  Of course, this doesn't work because the ids are not unique between the tables.

Is there anyway to keep the primary unique across two tables in mysql?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tablename . id` as the key in the Perl hash.

Comment: ta, that's what i've done now, i was hoping there was something cute i could do in mysql that would avoid this simply so i could avoid refactoring a load of code.  all the answers are good btw, this one had the least time / performance hit for my app.

Comment: It sounds like these things should actually be in the same master table, if they can be interchanged like this. Then these other two tables should be populated using the IDs from the master table.

Comment: the objects are quite different and really, I just need two distinct list, but sadly the app hasn't been written that way (it stuffs two different obj types into one hash for processing) and i don't want to do that level of rewrite at this stage. going to have to soon though.

Answer (score 0):

Hash   id1|id2  or whatever deliminator you want to use.  That was its always unique.

Answer (score 0):

There may be performance or other downsides, but consider using UUIDs as primary keys.